# How to import '.xlsx' from local directory using Vuejs without "type=file" to overwrite

Tags: node.js, vue.js, xlsx

I can import and export using nodejs as below.

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename);
await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename);
```

But I want to this method in the browser using Vuejs to overwrite a payload by API.
Unfortunately, I figured out that vuejs can't use 'fs' of nodejs.
And I found some ways that can import by "type=file" of HTML.
However, in my case I want to import and export without that. I hope that directly overwriting it.
Could you give me some advice for this case? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

That may not be possible since client (browser) and server are not the same thing.
This thread may help:
["fs is not defined" How can I use fs within a VueJS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729743/fs-is-not-defined-how-can-i-use-fs-within-a-vuejs-file)